# Rails assets: reset bootstrap css attributes so they don't conflict with google code's prettifier

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, pretty-print

I'm trying to use Bootstrap and google code prettyfier together but the end result is rather dissapointing. In the `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.2.1.1'
gem 'google-code-prettify-rails'
```

In `application.css`:

```
*= require bootstrap
*= require google-code-prettify-rails/prettify
```

In `application.js`:

```
//= require bootstrap$
//= require google-code-prettify-rails/prettify
//= require google-code-prettify-rails/lang-sql
```

And I run `prettyPrint()` on load from a .coffee script:

```
jQuery ->
  prettyPrint()
```

It all works fine, the `<code class="prettyprint lang-sql">...</code>` gets formatted. But alas the CSS that formats it is a mixture of Bootsrap's CSS and the prettyprint theme CSS, which displays ... ugly. Element Inspect shows the style applied coming from Bootstrap:

```
/* line 8, .../bootstrap-sass-2.2.1.1/vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_code.scss */
code,
pre {
  padding: 0 3px 2px;
  font-family: Monaco, Menlo, Consolas, "Courier New", monospace;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #333333;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

/* line 17, .../bootstrap-sass-2.2.1.1/vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_code.scss */
code {
  padding: 2px 4px;
  color: #d14;
  background-color: #f7f7f9;
  border: 1px solid #e1e1e8;
}
```

My question is

- is there a way to prevent the asset pipeline from including Bootstrap's own `_code.scss` ?
- if not, how do I reset Bootstrap's applied style?

Comment: Figured that adding a `code {display: block}`  displays a while lot nicer, but the question stands.